# equation solver in C segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("choose number");
  c();
}

c()
{
  printf("1. ax+b=0\n\n");
  printf("2. ax+by+c=0\n   dx+ey+f=0\n\n");
  int n;

  scanf("%d", &n);

  if (n > 3)
    wrong();
  if (n == 1)
    formula1();
  if (n == 2)
    formula2();
  if (n == 3)
    ;
  formula3();
}

wrong()
{
  printf("Please choose a number between 1 and 3.\n\n");
  c();
}

formula1()
{
  printf("ax+b=0\n");
  printf("Enter your values for a and b respectively, seperated by commas\n");
  float a, b, x;
  scanf("%f,%f,%f", &a, &b);
  x = -b / a;
  printf("x=-b/a\n");
  printf("=>x=%f", x);
  question();
}

formula2()
{
  printf("ax+by+c=0\n\ndx+ey+f=0\n");
  printf(
      "Enter your values for a, b, c, d ,e and f respectively, seperated by commas\n");
  float a, b, c, d, e, f, x, y;
  scanf("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
  x = ((f * b) - (c * e)) / ((a * e) - (d * b));
  y = ((c * d) - (f * a)) / ((e * a) - (d * b));
  printf("=>x=%f", x);
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("=>y=%f", y);
  question();
}

question()
{
  char t;
  printf("\n\nanother equation?\ny/n?\n");
  if (t == 'y')
  {
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    c();
  }
  else if (t != 'n')
    question();
}
```

I have this code, which in short solves 3 equations. 
When you select any choice it seems to run the question method multiple times then quits due to a `segmentation fault: 11`

Could someone please point out where I am going wrong. Any other help with my code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `scanf("%f,%f,%f",&a, &b);` What exactly are you trying to do here? And it's important to check here `x=-b/a;` that `a != 0`.

Comment: Please format (indent) your code a little.

Comment: You might like to compile with all warnings on (-Wall on gcc), fix the code until no more warnings appear, then run the program using valgrind und fix the code until no more warnings appear, finally you are free to come back and ask questions (if then still necessary).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one problem:

```
scanf("%f,%f,%f",&a, &b);
```

Only two arguments are supplied for the three values.

Answer (score 4):

There is no input function like `scanf()` in `question()` and so if `t` is not 'y' or 'n' by chance, you get an endless recursion until stack size is exceeded ...

Comment: That, and the code is referencing a function called `choice` which isn't included in the post.